# Хэш функция, хэш таблица

Tags: хеширование, c++

Не могу сделать защиту от ввода существующего таб номера. Функция сама есть prov. Вот как ей правильно воспользоваться? Я пробовал чере цикл и условие и не получается.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 103

struct info
    {
     int tab;
     char fam[20];
     float oklad;
     info()
     {
      tab=0; oklad=0;
     }
    }; info T[N];

int hesh(int key){ return key % N;}
void forms(char fl[]);//formiruet hesh tabl T iz faila fl
void output();//vivod mas T na ekran
int search(int p);//funkc vozvrash index zapisi s tab nomerom=p ili -1
void add (info g);//dobavl zapic g v tabl T
void del (info g);//udalenie

void main()
    {
     int z,k,s;
     info m,n;
     clrscr();
     forms("1.txt");
     cout<<endl;
     output();
     cout<<"Vvedidet tab fam oklad novogo sotr:"<<endl;
     cout<<"Tab nom:";
     while (cin>>m.tab)
        {
         cout<<"Familiya:"; cin>>m.fam;
         cout<<"Oklad:"; cin>>m.oklad;
         int i=search(m.tab);
         if (i!=-1)
            {
             cout<<"3anogo"<<endl;
             T[i]=m;
            }
            else {add(m); break;}
        }
     ofstream f("1.txt",ios::app);
     f<<m.tab<<'\t'<<m.fam<<'\t'<<'\t'<<m.oklad<<endl;
     output();
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
         {
          cout<<"\n\nVvedite tab nom poiska:";
          cin>>z;
          k=search(z);
          if (k==-1) cout<<"Ne naiden"; else
            cout<<T[k].tab<<'\t'<<T[k].fam<<'\t'<<T[k].oklad<<'\n';
         }
     cout<<endl<<"Vvedidet tab nomer del:"<<endl;
     cin>>n.tab;
     del(n);
     output();
     getch();
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void add (info g)
    {
     int j=0;
     int i=hesh(g.tab);
     while (T[i].tab!=0 && j<N)
        {
         i=hesh(i+1);
         j++;
        }
     if (j==N){ cout<<"Tabl perepolnena";getch(); exit (0);}
        else T[i]=g;
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void forms(char fl[])
    {
     ifstream F(fl);
     info x;
     while (F>>x.tab>>x.fam>>x.oklad)
     add(x);
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void output()
      {
       cout<<"index tab fam oklad   "<<endl;
       for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        if (T[i].tab!=0)
            cout<<i<<'\t'<<T[i].tab<<'\t'<<T[i].fam<<'\t'<<T[i].oklad<<'\n';
      }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int search (int p)
      {
       int j=0, i=hesh(p);
       while (j++<N && T[i].tab)
        {
         if (T[i].tab==p)
            return i;
         i=hesh(i+1);
        }
       return -1;
      }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void del (info g)
      {
       int i=hesh(g.tab);
       if (search) T[i].tab=NULL;
      }
```

Comment: Вообще-то, называть функции транслитом — моветон.

Comment: @Fint, какой-то сомнительный алгоритм поиска и в add() и в prov() (надо думать это вместо стандартного find()?). 

Попробуйте просто линейное опробывание (не вычисляйте снова хэш, просто ++i в while).

А удалять таким образом элементы из хэш таблицы с открытой адресацией (это название метода, который Вы используете) однозначно нельзя. При удалении слот надо помечать, как свободный (и это использует функция add), а вот find рассматривает такой слот как коллизию (о которых, как мне кажется (?) Вы вообще забыли (по крайней мере в prov)).

Comment: Если честно я в c++. очень плохо разбираюсь, но препод сказал что правильно и сам помогал. Буду тщательнее изучать метод.

Comment: @Fint, да, с Вашим конкретным hesh(i + 1) в add() я погорячился. 

Проблема у Вас в том, что Вы не учитываете возможность коллизий в prov() и poisk(). На самом деле poisk() должна быть какой-то такой

    int poisk (int p) {
        int j = 0, i = hesh(p);
        while (j++ < N && T[i].tab) {
          if (T[i].tab == p)
             return i;
          i = hesh(i + 1); // так же, как в add()!!!
        }
        return -1;
    }

Насколько я понимаю, у Вас `tab` целые **положительные** числа. Тогда удаленные можно помечать `tab = -1`. Тогда add можно модифицировать и занимать слоты с tab -1

Comment: Спасибо! Точно работает. Тяжелова-то конечно. А вот функцию prov мб я зря создал на проверку? Без неё не обойтипсь?

Comment: Конечно, prov() в таком виде абсолютно не нужна. Достаточно poisk().

И Вы, все-таки, переименуйте функции на что-нибудь "англо"-подобное (в google переводчик есть).

Comment: Переименовал функции. Вот я так и не пойму, как тогда сделать чтобы введённые таб номера не записывались ещё раз(все данные в общем), если они уже есть в файле? Допустим ввёл таб номер нового сотрудника и если он есть, заново вводить, если нету, тогда и остальные данные вводить.

Comment: @Fint, если речь, например, о forms(), то очень просто

    while (F>>x.tab>>x.fam>>x.oklad) 
      if (poisk(x.tab) == -1)
         add(x);

Ищете, если такого еще нет, то добавляете.

Comment: form только формирует хеш таблицу. я пробовал через while в главной функции, он всё равно записывает что-то введённые данные, хотя не должен по логике. В общем на этом я и застопорился. Даже мне пришлось записывать в файл новые данные тоже в главной функции, т.к. в add она не правильно делала это.

Comment: "таб номера. Функция сама есть prov" Браза! Чо почём, что спикать залетел в наши пенаты? Ну, ты поэл.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что функцию сделали возвращающей константу. Пусть хоть T[i].tab == r.tab возвращает. Тогда можно будет:

```
if (prov(val)) 
   add(val); 
else 
   cout << "Идите нафиг";
```

UPD:
Что-то типа этого:

```
bool success = false;
do{
   cout << "Введите номер" << endl;
   cin >> val;
   if (prov(val)) {
      add(val); 
      success = true;
   }
}while(!success);

// Вводим остальное...
```

Comment: К сожалению не проходит. Я сейчас по понятнее разъясню. Нужно чтобы при вводе таб номера, если нету такого в списке, идёт дальше и заполняю фамилию и оклад, если же я ввожу таб номер и он уже есть, выводит сообщение чтобы ввести заного и ввожу заного таб номер.

Comment: Ну это ж только элемент, а пристроить можешь так, как душе угодно. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Fint, у меня там комментарии закончились.

Конкретно помочь не могу, т.к. вижу только старый код, а Вы говорите о проблемах с уже как-то правленным.

Comment: Обновил на новый код

Comment: @Fint, IMHO `while` в `main()` д.б. каким-то таким:


     while (cin >> m.tab) {
       cin>>m.fam; cin>>m.oklad;
       int i = search(m.tab);
       if (i != -1) {
          cout << "Update\n";
          T[i] = m;
       } else 
          add(m);
     }

Обратите внимание, Вы реализуете не множество, а мультимножество. add() **всегда** добавляет новую запись в таблицу, независимо от ключа (есть ли уже такой в таблице). 

Поэтому устранение дубликатов возлагается на алгоритм ввода данных.

Кстати, в de() у Вас очевидная ошибка. Подумайте пока сами (+ add() под новый del измените).

Comment: avp Вам виднее конечно вы специалист, у меня программа так-то работает и удаляет. А вот проблема с удаления записи с файла, осталась. Можно в другой фал переписать игнорируя, найденную запись, но так нельзя, а вот как просто удалить из сущ файла не знаю. Я вот только прочитал, что с удалением сложнее. Там нужно помечать удалённый элемент.

Comment: @Fint, Ваша функция `del()` (код, который я вижу в вопросе) работает неправильно. Она просто делает свободным первый же слот таблицы, полученный из `i=hesh(g.tab);`, т.к. `if (search)` **всегда даст true**.

Вам надо написать

    void del (info g) {
       int i=search(g.tab);
       if (i != -1) T[i].tab= -1;
    }

иначе (если обнулять) возникнут проблемы с коллизиями в последующих search.

--

А что **надо делать** с файлом? 

Наверное, надо накопить удаляемые номера в отдельной таблице, а потом просто переписать файл, не копируя такие строки.

(тут места мало и у меня комментарии конч.